# Cant import AppKit in ObjC-module of SwiftPM

Tags: objective-c, import, swift-package-manager

I tried to import AppKit in a Header of an Module of a Swift-Packet with this code:

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
```

But the compiler threw this error:

```
fatal error: 'AppKit/AppKit.h' file not found
```

Should I specify it somehow as dependency in the Package.swift file of the Package?

Thanks in advance

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just resolved this issue by linking with this Framework in Xcode.
I don't know how to specify that in the Package.swift file, but for know it works.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Note that Swift Package Manager (SPM) is intended for the Server Side Swift, not for the Client Side. Concretely, AppKit was probably not ported to the Server Side Swift, so you could not be able to use AppKit with SPM. AppKit is part of the Objective-C runtime. SPM does not take the Objective-C runtime into account during its build.

From [swift.org, Platform Support](https://swift.org/about/#platform-support):

> Our goal is to provide source compatibility for Swift across all platforms, even though the actual implementation mechanisms may differ from one platform to the next. The primary example is that the Apple platforms include the Objective-C runtime, which is required to access Apple platform frameworks such as UIKit and AppKit. On other platforms, such as Linux, no Objective-C runtime is present, because it isn’t necessary.
>
> The Swift core libraries project aims to extend the cross-platform capabilities of Swift by providing portable implementations of fundamental Apple frameworks (such as Foundation) without dependencies on the Objective-C runtime. Although the core libraries are in an early stage of development, they will eventually provide improved source compatibility for Swift code across all platforms.